# how to get base 64 code and store it in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want  a piece of code to get the base 64 code  of an image when i select a file or upload and store it in a cookiei want to pass this image to a pop up window with out uploading it on server

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    //var allcookies = document.cookie;
    //alert("all cookie"+allcookies);
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


function mh_realtime_preview(input,input_id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.cookie= "img1_code = " + e.target.result;
            document.cookie="test=value";
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        mh_realtime_preview(this,'#img_id');
        setTimeout( function() {alert(readCookie("img1_code"));} ,1000);
    }); 
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="imgInp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set a cookie with this data in it, every request you make to the host will send the cookie data until you delete it. That's what cookies are for. Are you **sure** this is what you want? It's quite an unusual approach. A better question would be "How to pass data to window opened with `window.open`?"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cookies you could use sessionStorage for storing the data.

code to set the data,

```
sessionStorage.setItem('item-name','item-data');
```

code to get the data,

```
sessionStorage.getItem('item-name');
```

Note: this is HTML 5 based Storage object so some browsers may not support it.

`localStorage` can also be used instead of `sessionStorage` in case if you want to save it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any idea about the coockies.

But for base64 there is an inbuild function in javascript

1)btoa() :- to encode

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp

2)atob() :- to decode

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp

Comment: (a) an answer that means nothing when the links are removed isn't a valid answer. You should replace your links with a simple code example. (b) http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not intended to store images, sounds, etc. The space used to store cookies is often limited, and users may clear cookies after each session.

In addition to this, as *spender* already pointed out, cookie data is always passed to the server at each request.

If you just want to pass a base64 image from a window to its popup child, you should just use a JS var to keep the base64 string, then dynamically create the img element on the popup with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would store data in javascript variable and use that variable in popup window where needed.

e.g.

```
// Main window
window.base64Data = data;
window.open("popup.html");

// popup.html
var base64Data = window.opener.base64Data;
```